# Optaplanner spring-boot loading resources issue (works only with unit test)

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, optaplanner

I'am trying to build a solution with optaplanner by loading an xml file by resource. When i run it in a unit test, it works just fine. But when I try to run it when my Spring-boot application is running, I think it doesn't read the resources properly.

This is our config xml file

```
<!-- Domain model configuration -->


<solutionClass>be.infofarm.backend.domain.Internship.solution.InternshipSolution</solutionClass>
<entityClass>be.infofarm.backend.domain.Internship.Student</entityClass>

<!--<environmentMode>FAST_ASSERT</environmentMode>-->

<!-- Score configuration -->
<scoreDirectorFactory>
    <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT</scoreDefinitionType>

    <scoreDrl>InternshipCalculator.drl</scoreDrl>
    <initializingScoreTrend>ONLY_DOWN</initializingScoreTrend>
</scoreDirectorFactory>

<constructionHeuristic>
    <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
</constructionHeuristic>

<localSearch>
    <forager>
        <acceptedCountLimit>800</acceptedCountLimit>
    </forager>
</localSearch>

<localSearch>
    <acceptor>
        <entityTabuSize>20</entityTabuSize>
    </acceptor>
</localSearch>

<termination>
    <secondsSpentLimit>10</secondsSpentLimit>
</termination>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately there's not really enough information here for anyone to help you. I'd suggest reading through [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then coming back and editing your post to include additional information.

Comment: Turn on `DEBUG` logging (see optaplanner docs section about it) and check if you're running the same number of steps (= iterations). If you compare the 2 runs, the output should have the same score at the same iteration.

Comment: We've put it on DEBUG logging and when we compare the 2 iterations there is a significant difference. With the Spring boot run, there are much more LS steps than with the unit test run.
Also, the Spring boot run doesn't add up the soft score we have initialized in our drool file. And when we run the Unit test, it only adds up a soft score we've initialized in our drool file but it ignores the hard constraints. We have replaced the <scannAnnotatedClasses> with <entityClass> and <solutionClass>. We don't get any exceptions when we run the application

Comment: How many `InternshipCalculator.drl` files do you have? Try namespacing it. Sounds like the 2 environments are not pickiing up the same file (and therefore the same set of score rules).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `<scanAnnotatedClasses>` on Spring Boot: it throws an exception due to ClassLoading magic that is not compatible with org.reflections's scanning.

You should see that exception and post that stacktrace in the question - if you don't - and if there really is an exception - first fix whatever is eating your exception before doing anything else. Eating exceptions is very very bad.

Replace `<scanAnnotatedClasses>` with `<solutionClass>` and `<entityClass>` elements.